# Distributions on fat Cantor sets

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, cantor-set

Suppose we have a probability distribution that is supported on the fat Cantor set.   For details on the fat Cantor sets see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set).

A have a few questions about these distributions.

1. Is there a good reference that treats these distributions in a systematic way.
2. Does such a distribution have a density?

I am very fascinated by this sets would really like to start reading about them. However, need a good starting place. I am particularly, interested in applications to probability theory.